# How to replace strings with int in sublist?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split above special letters '/' or '_' whatever comes first in the string column.

Here is the sample of the dataset(df2):

```
    4. 발견장소 코딩사유    Unnamed : 1
1    67488                  교외/야산_등산로 계곡 앞
2    100825                 자택_자택 방안 텐트
3.   101199                 숙박업소_게스트하우스 21층 복도
```

I converted Unnamed: 1 column like this:

```
    4. 발견장소 코딩사유    Unnamed : 1
1    67488                  [[교외],[야산_등산로 계곡 앞]]
2    100825                 [[자택],[자택 방안 텐트]]
3.   101199                 [[숙박업소],[게스트하우스 21층 복도]]
```

I'm trying to replace the strings with numbers like this. Here is the desired output:

```
    4. 발견장소 코딩사유     Unnamed : 1
1    67488   [[7],[야산_등산로 계곡 앞]]
2    100825  [[1],[자택 방안 텐트]]
3    101199  [[6],[게스트하우스 21층 복도]]
```

What I tried:

```
for i in range(1,122):
  # KEY값 추출
  index_key = df2['4. 발견장소 코딩사유'][i]

  # FIND_PLACETP값 추출
  index_rawdata = df.loc[df['KEY'] == index_key,'FIND_PLACETP'].index[0]
  num = df['FIND_PLACETP'][index_rawdata]

  # text split
  findplace = df2['Unnamed: 1'].str.split('/|_',expand=False)

  # replace words with numbers
  findplace[i][0] = findplace[i][0].str.replace('자택','1')
  findplace[i][0]

  findplace[i][0].str.replace(dict(zip(['자택','친척집','지인집','학교|직장','공공장소','숙박업소','교외|야산','병원','기타'],
                                   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])),regex=True)
```

but it caused the error like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-b8929ebb1248> in <module>
     11 
     12   # replace words with numbers
---> 13   findplace[i][0] = findplace[i][0].str.replace('자택','1')
     14   findplace[i][0]
     15   # findplace[i][0].str.replace(dict(zip(['자택','친척집','지인집','학교|직장','공공장소','숙박업소','교외|야산','병원','기타'],

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pandas`, with your method, you are referring to a `value` instead of `row` or `column`. In `findplace[i][0]`, `i` is your `column` name and `0` is your `row` name, and it is returning the `value` of column `i` where row is `0`.

I don't really know, either you are trying to use `replace` on `row` (with index name as `0`) or the whole `column` and `row`.

For the whole column:

```py
findplace[i] = findplace[i].str.replace('자택','1') #[0] is removed
```

For the row with index name as `0`:

```py
findplace[i][0] = findplace[i][0].replace('자택','1')
#findplace[i][0] is a string so replace can be applied directly
```